# Navigation li with arrowkeys and entering with enter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need help to click on the LI i get from a function, it's hard to explain and i have no idea why it does not work.. But the page is here http://japseyz.dk/Projects/Code/ (Type Razer in to search field).. 
You can navigate with the arrowkeys and the enter button should redirect you to the page, just like normal clicking does

Comment: any code u could show us? a fiddle maybe?

Comment: It works fine, what's your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what are you testing for but the alert should be:

```
var test = $(".selected a").attr("href");
```

instead of

```
var test = $(".selected:first-child").html();
```

and then, replace `alert(test)` with `document.location.href = test;`

Comment: okay, the html() was just testing ^^ but thanks, i will try this soon ;)